# Android 5.0 ART native DeleteGlobalReference(jobject) is failing

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, native, android-runtime

I have an SDK/NDK based app that creates native buffers and then reads/writes data to there to communicate through JNI bridge.
in 4.4 (DALVIK) it functions OK - or at least it was not throwing an exception. Once ART became mandatory, i.e. Lollipop - it now fails on app close/exit.
Creating the direct buffer here:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_class_nativeOnDirect(JNIEnv* jenv,   jobject obj, jobject   m, jobject mv){
  GLubyte* _dData;
_dData = (GLubyte*)jenv->GetDirectBufferAddress(m);
}
```

Clearing the direct data:

```
 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_class_nativeOnFreeNativeBuffer(JNIEnv* jenv, jobject obj, jobject m){
 jenv->DeleteGlobalRef(m);
}
```

After some research into this - still not exactly clear to me as to why this happens.
BTW - if the "DeleteGlobalref(jobjct) does not happen - the exception is not thrown.
Afraid of a memory leak here.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tested your code on Android 4.4.4 with ART enabled instead of Dalvik?

Comment: yes - and in Dalvik on 4.4 it was not failing on exit - in Art it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't call `DeleteGlobalRef` on a local ref - only on the actual `jobject` pointers that you've got returned from `NewGlobalRef`. So in this case, as long as you aren't calling `NewGlobalRef`, you don't need to call `DeleteGlobalRef` either.

You only need to use `NewGlobalRef` if you store a reference to an object on the native side, for use after the JNI function call returns.

ART is a little bit stricter than dalvik when it comes to using the JNI API correctly, so the code has been incorrect all along, it just hasn't triggered any errors. See http://android-developers.blogspot.fi/2011/07/debugging-android-jni-with-checkjni.html for tips on how to enable CheckJNI for stricter checking, to be able to catch issues like these earlier.

Comment: Thanks - I suspected as much - and good to have a pointer to the JNI check blog - maybe less guessing on my part with this.